# Get volley request tag in response

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I'm using volley and I have a queue to call some APIs. The queue is filled from a database.

before adding request to `volley` request queue I set request tag by calling

`jsonObjectRequest.setTag(id);`

In response, I want to remove a column from the `database` that column id is equal to request tag id.

So, How can I get request tag in `HttpRequest` `response`?

Comment: This might help you [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36127870/how-to-set-tag-to-the-request-and-get-it-from-response-volley-asynchronous-reque)

Comment: @MohammedFarhan So you mean I have to compile volley source code in my application?

Comment: exactly that answer is accepted, so you need to follow it.

Comment: You actually don't have to have the volley source code, you can override the `Request` class and make your own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First create a Listener that give response from your volly class

```
/** Callback interface for delivering parsed responses. */
public interface Listener {
    /** Called when a response is received. */
    public void onResponse(Object tag, JSONObject response);
    public void onErrorResponse(Object tag, VolleyError error);
}
```

And now create method as below where you pass listener and tag and call volly request. in response you able get tag and response at same time.

```
public void callApi(String url, final Listener listener, final Object tag){
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    listener.onResponse(tag,response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            listener.onErrorResponse(tag,error);
        }
    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
}
```

Its just sample code, You can modify on your requirement. If you need any help comment.